# Pressure difference/drop(or loss?) in a Laminar pipe flow

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Consider a "pressure-driven" flow ( inlet $P_1$ and outlet $P_2$  pressures "imposed" by an engineer) in a pipe of some length.

Under a steady-flow, fully developed region :

**My understanding**:

For "this" pressure difference or drop or gradient $\left(\dfrac{P_1 - P_2}{L} = \dfrac{\Delta P}{L}\right)$, there will exist a flow rate, $Q$.

Further, if there exists a **"*frictional LOSS*"**, we cannot achieve the same flow rate for the imposed pressure difference, $P_1 - P_2$.

Now, to calculate the **frictional loss**, I cannot understand why textbooks use the same nomenclature/notation/ variable of pressure difference/drop, **as $\dfrac{\Delta P}{L}$ is an externally imposed parameter and not a result of flow happening**.

All the textbooks use the same notation $\left(\dfrac{\Delta P}{L}\right)$ for the pressure difference/drop that "drives the flow"  **AND** equate the same as frictional loss and write an expression (with density $\rho$)

I am missing the lead somewhere. Help me out!

Comment: All losses whether due to friction, bends, constrictions can be represented in terms of a head loss term. One way of defining all the "losses" in equivalent form to see which is the most significant in a given situation.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me, if "I impose" my delP as 50Pa to drive the flow, will the Frictional losses(as the expression in the text says delP) also be 50Pa? Then there is just only loss!?

Comment: Check out Mechanics of Fluids by Massey.

Comment: If you have an empty pipe, there is no dP/L, right? The fact that there is a flow happening means there must be a pressure gradient. I do not think saying dP/L is independent of the flow is correct. I'm having trouble understanding the last paragraph, can you post pictures of the equations you are having issue with?

Comment: @J.Ari thanks for your reply. I am not saying dp/l is independent of the flow. One flow rate can have only one dp/l ( given the Diameter stays constant). I am confused how the FRICTIONAL PRESSURE LOSS  is same as gradient. Gradient(dp/l)  is something we impose, while loss is the by-product of the flow happening .

Comment: For the sake of completeness, we should note that even if the diameter stays constant, the dP/L value can change if the fluid density, fluid viscosity, or pipe roughness changes. However, we're talking about a specific case, so that's what I'll try to focus on. I think it would help if you can post pictures of the pages that have the equations you are taking issue with - I'm struggling to understand the notation aspect of your question.